# wordpress page navigation numeric pagination showing same posts on each navigation

Tags: pages, navigation

Hi I have a similar issue with page nav, we are showing listing and due to the amount want to page them, We have got most of the code sorted but seems to just duplicate the page and not sure the reason why. This is the code:

```
        endwhile; 
    echo '<hr>';
    $GLOBALS['wp_query']->max_num_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; 
    ct_numeric_pagination_local();      

    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

echo '</ul>';

    echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
```

}
}

function ct_numeric_pagination_local() {

```
global $wp_query;

/** Stop execution if there's only 1 page */
if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 )
    return;

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$max   = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );

/** Add current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 1 )
    $links[] = $paged;

/** Add the pages around the current page to the array */
if ( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
    $links[] = $paged - 2;
}

if ( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 2;
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
}

echo '<div class="pagination"><ul>' . "\n";

/** Previous Post Link */
if ( get_previous_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li>%s</li>' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link() );

/** Link to first page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' class="current"' : '';

    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), '1' );

    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>';
}

/** Link to current page, plus 2 pages in either direction if necessary */
sort( $links );
foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' class="current"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $link );
}

/** Link to last page, plus ellipses if necessary */
if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) )
        echo '<li>…</li>' . "\n";

    $class = $paged == $max ? ' class="current"' : '';
    printf( '<li%s><a href="%s">%s</a></li>' . "\n", $class, esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $max );
}

/** Next Post Link */
if ( get_next_posts_link() )
    printf( '<li id="next-page-link">%s</li>' . "\n", get_next_posts_link() );
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</ul></div>' . "\n";
```

}

Comment: what is the code of your template with the loop? have you reviewed https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination ?

Comment: There is a lot of code for this section it is a shortcode that we have added the nav to but the page just replicates itself. I have checked the codex